# Why is requests-html not returning the element for kahoot.it?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I'm trying to create a kahoot bot with requests-html. When I search for the game-pin element via identifier ('#game-pin'), it returns as "[]". From what I can tell, the page is loaded dynamically via Javascript. Supposedly, r.html.render should allow me to grab the elements but it responds the same with "[]"

I expected it to return an element but it still returned blank.

This is my code:

```
import requests-html

session = requests-html.HTMLSession()

r = session.get('https://kahoot.it/')

#this might take awhile the first time ran
r.html.render()

elem = r.html.find('#game-input')

print(elem)
```

Comment: What exactly the bot gonna do? And what element you are expecting to be returned?

Comment: I intend for the bot to spam join the kahoot. I'm expecting the pin button element to be returned (right click on enter pin and do inspect). In this case however, what the bot is for doesn't really pertain to the problem. I can make it work if I figure out how to render the element. I think I found the source JS code (https://cdn.amplitude.com/libs/amplitude-5.3.0-min.gz.js), but I have no idea what to do with it.